# How to run add menu to bottom in full screen mode?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, legacy

I recently faced an issue when we decided to upgrade our kids painting app to support Android 3/4 while maintaining support for Android 2.1. But a series issue soon occurred, users are giving us bad review because our app now has the Action Bar on top - they demanded the "full screen mode" back!

So now I am faced with this issue - we need to have target SDK > 10 but yet we do not want Action Bar. While searching for the forum we see that some (@user1076637) suggested that we can run in "legacy mode" (targetSdkVersion < 14) - and we have tried 11/12/13 while removing ActionBar (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"), the menu is nowhere to be seen in our Android 4 device.

Is there a solution to this? We just wanted something like the legacy mode where the menu button is at bottom? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX, 0, "Add").setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
    return  true;
}
```